# match group of names with other group of names with number in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, match

```
Entity  name_b  number_b    name_s  number_s
0   1   Zyla    {1, 2, 3}   Zeela   {1, 2, 3}
1   1   Zyla 620 {1}        Zylo    {1}
2   1   Xyla 620 {2}        Xylaa   {2}
3   1   GCP Zyla {4, 7}     Ann Zyl {103}
4   1   Zy        {103} 

I would like to get output as:
    Entity      number     name_b    name_s
0      1           1        Zyla       Zeela                                            
1      1           1        Zyla       Zylo                                                
2      1           2        Zyla       Zeela
3      1           2        Zyla       Xylaa
4      1           3        Zyla       Zeela                                                 
5      1           1        Zyla 620   Zeela                                                 
6      1           1        Zyla 620   Zylo                                                 
7      1           2        Xyla 620   Zeela                                                
8      1           2        Xyla 620   Xylaa
9      1           4        GCP Zyla     -
10     1           7        GCP Zyla     -
11     1          103       Zy         Ann Zyl
```

I would like to compare the group of name_b with group of name_s based on the number_b and number_s and find the possible matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the data you have in `number_b`/`number_s` are sets:

```py
df1 = (
    df[["Entity", "name_b", "number_b"]]
    .explode("number_b")
    .dropna()
    .rename(columns={"number_b": "number"})
)
df2 = (
    df[["name_s", "number_s"]]
    .explode("number_s")
    .dropna()
    .rename(columns={"number_s": "number"})
)

out = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    on="number",
    how="outer",
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    Entity    name_b number   name_s
0        1      Zyla      1    Zeela
1        1      Zyla      1     Zylo
2        1  Zyla 620      1    Zeela
3        1  Zyla 620      1     Zylo
4        1      Zyla      2    Zeela
5        1      Zyla      2    Xylaa
6        1  Xyla 620      2    Zeela
7        1  Xyla 620      2    Xylaa
8        1      Zyla      3    Zeela
9        1  GCP Zyla      4      NaN
10       1  GCP Zyla      7      NaN
11       1        Zy    103  Ann Zyl
```